# must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I cant't figure out why I am getting this error. Everything looks properly. 
Import store to the component like this.

```
import store from './store';


new Vue({
    components: {
     SomeComponent
    },
    store
});
```

My store looks like this

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import * as getters from './getters';
import * as actions from './actions';
import mutations from './mutations';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
       something
    }
})
```

Please any help.
Thanks

> Uncaught Error: [vuex] must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance.

Comment: Ou.. I'e resolved  this problem. I had 'vue' instead of 'vue-loader' in webpack. So, *** happens

Answer (score 31):

Using Vue CLI and setting up like this works for me

in store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    something: ['something']
  }
})
```

in main.js
    import Vue from 'vue'

```
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: I also have the same setup. First it works but after when I ran `yarn build` I suddenly got the error. Any idea?

Comment: The Vuex should be imported and `Vue.use(vuex)` in your store.js file (where the `new Vuex()` declaration is) and not the `app.js` file, except if you prefer to layout all your setup in a single file

Answer (score 17):

I've had a similar problem, and turns out that my modules were returning a Vuex.Store instance instead of a javascript object.
My files was like:

**app.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
...
import store from './store'
...
```

**store/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)
import myModule from './my-module'
...
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: { myModule }
    ....
})
```

**my-module/index.js** (Here was my problem)

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
...
export default new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    state: { ... },
    ...
})
```

My mistake was that I must have only one store, the root store, the others are modules of root. So I must not instantiate a new store, but return a config object instead. Like so:

**my-module/index.js** (Corrected version)

```js
...
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: { ... },
    ...
}
```

So, if anyone arrived here with the same problem, I hope it can save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart for how they do it in their sample app.

**app.js**

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/App.vue'
import store from './store'
import { currency } from './currency'

Vue.filter('currency', currency)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as getters from './getters'
import cart from './modules/cart'
import products from './modules/products'
import createLogger from '../../../src/plugins/logger'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions,
  getters,
  modules: {
    cart,
    products
  },
  strict: debug,
  plugins: debug ? [createLogger()] : []
})
```

Answer (score 0):

#katieh
Ou.. I'e resolved this problem. I had 'vue' instead of 'vue-loader' in webpack. So, *** happens then i remove vue-loader work well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31423254)

Answer (score 0):

you literally need to add something to the store; a state, module or a getter

Answer (score -3):

I create a repositorie: [vue-use-vuex](https://github.com/hezedu/vue-use-vuex) to solved this bug.

You can Use it to fixed:

```
npm install vue-use-vuex --save
```

add one line code in you entry:

```
import 'vue-use-vuex'
```

The error will not be seen.

Comment: This isn't really a solution